# How to manage scala enum with Anorm?

Tags: scala, enums, anorm

I want to create user roles by using enums (thought that it would be the best idea).

How should I proceed with this?

My current code looks like this:

```scala
object UserRole extends Enumeration {
  type UserRole = Value
  val admin, user, manager = Value
}    
case class User(id: Long, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String, email: String, role: UserRole)
```

So how should I define the user "simple":

```scala
val simple = {
    get[Long]("user.id") ~
      get[String]("user.firstname") ~
      get[String]("user.lastname") ~
      get[String]("user.password") ~
      get[String]("user.email") ~
      get[UserRole]("user.role")  map {
      case id~firstname~lastname~password~email~role => User(id, firstname, lastname, password, email, role)
    }
  }
```

And how should I save it to database?

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'),
    firstname varchar(60),
    lastname varchar(60),
    password varchar(255),
    email varchar(60),
    role varchar(40)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anorm doesn't support scala enums (and scala enums are pretty bad, in my opinion). What I usually do is create another case class with it's own parser and table space, and `JOIN` it to relevant queries. The `UserRole` can be parsed in `User` by composing it within `User.simple`.

```
case class UserRole(id: Long, name: String)

object UserRole {
    val simple: RowParser[UserRole] = {
        get[Long]("roles.id") ~
        get[String]("roles.name") map {
            case id~name => UserRole(id, name)
       }
    }
}

case class User(id: Long, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String, email: String, role: UserRole)

object User {

    val simple: RowParser[User] = {
        get[Long]("user.id") ~
        get[String]("user.firstname") ~
        get[String]("user.lastname") ~
        get[String]("user.password") ~
        get[String]("user.email") ~
        UserRole.simple map {
            case id~firstname~lastname~password~email~role => 
                User(id, firstname, lastname, password, email, role)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, you could model your roles as with a sealed trait.

```
sealed trait UserRole
case object Admin extends UserRole
case object User extends UserRole
case object Manager extends UserRole
```

Then provide a anorm reader for your type.

```
implicit val column: Column[UserRole] = {
  Column.nonNull1 { (value, meta) =>
    val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
      case "Admin" => Right(Admin)
      case "User" => Right(User)
      case "Manager" => Right(Manager)
      case unknown => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(s"unknown UserRole from $unknown"))
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the type in your row parser like `get[UserRole]`

Note the matching on the string, the obviously a pretty budget but you get the idea.

For more details see the docs here, https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#Column-parsers